# find multiple fields from an array in mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find multiple fields from a table in mongodb database from a given array,

```
const tags = ["da vinci", "portofino"]

const tagArray = await Tag.find({ value: [tags] });
```

the Tag table looks like this

```
const TagSchema  = new Schema({
  value: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
});
```

I need to get 2 tag objects like the following

```
_id:5cfe978ed5d0e307c7931564
value:"PORTOFINO"

_id:5cfe978ed5d0e307c7931560
value:"Da Vinci"
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `$in`... `const tagArray = await Tag.find({ value: { $in: [tags] }})`

Comment: @Fanpark Thanks for the quick response, however I get this error CastError: Cast to string failed for value "[ 'Portofino', 'Pilots\'s watches' ]" at path "value" for model "tags"

Comment: Did u try 
var query = { values: ["da vinci", "portofino"] };
  dbo.collection("cities").find(query).toArray();

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

for future reference it should be

```
const tagArray = await Tag.find({ value: { $in: tags } });
```